# Qt into ObjectiveC code

Tags: c++, objective-c, qt

As i'am coding in objective-c, i'am wondering if i can put some Qt code in my objective-c project and compile it all together  ? i did a research but the answers were kind of shady. If this is possible, do you have a hint or an answer on how to do this please ? Thank you.

Comment: You might want to read about [Objective-C++](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C#Objective-C.2B.2B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, as I do this the other way round - Use Objective C in a Qt project with Qt Creator. That's easy to do by adding .m or .mm files to the project and linking to the required frameworks.

To add Qt to XCode requires creating a project file from Qt. [This](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/53249-Setting-QT-in-Xcode-step-by-step-guide) post seems to describe steps required to do this.